# How to analyse linked 2x2 tables from multiple raters?

Tags: repeated-measures, reliability, contingency-tables, agreement-statistics

**Comment:** heavily edited, both to clarify and to fix a mistake. First 7 comments below refer to the previous version.

I have an experiment where 3 raters go over the same data 2 times each, trying to make a diagnosis. The second of these two passes serves as the gold standard, and I want to compare the results of the first one against certain variable (info source, two possible values). Specifically, I am interested in the cases where the raters were not sure of their diagnosis.

So, I have a 2x2 table for each rater: counts of "unsure" cases becoming (or not) "sure" in the gold standard, vs. info source. The inter-rater agreement is very poor (being unsure is a very subjective thing; FWIW, when they are sure, they agree pretty well), but the data is obviously not independent (so I can't use Cochran-Mantel-Haenszel, can I?). So – is there any reasonable (and preferably reasonably standard) way to combine these three 2x2 tables to tell whether there is a dependence on the information source?

Comment: Some additional clarity would be helpful.  In paragraph 1, '3 raters 3 times each' sounds like 9 tables, whereas in para 2, (a) sounds like 3 tables.  This makes a difference.  Also, what are these tables (e.g., rater said yes/no X actually yes/no, etc)?  How is "unsure" being assessed?  It's not the same thing as the lack of inter-rater agreement.

Comment: @gung I am interested here in 3 2x2 tables (one per rater); they are a slice through the original larger contingency table. "Unsure" means that the rater says "I can't give you a diagnosis".

Comment: 3 tables helps.  What are the 2x2 (rater can give diagnosis/can't X what?)?

Comment: @gung Columns are the two different info sources. Rows are yes/no for a rather complicated question. The tables' entries are counts (# of cases).

Comment: So, table 1 is rater A yes/no X rater B yes/no; table 2 is rater A yes/no X rater C yes/no; and table 3 is rater B yes/no X rater C yes/no; and, "no"="unsure".  Do I have it right at this point?

Comment: @gung Almost. Table 1 is (rater 1 yes/no) X (info source 1 / info source 2). "Yes" and "no" are for a complicated question involving being unsure.

Comment: @gung question edited to clarify and fix a mistake. Thanks a lot for your help so far!